# Building a General Tree - creating too many brothers?

Tags: c++, data-structures, tree

I'm trying to construct a general tree with c++. the data structure i'm using is a Node class that has 2 pointers. pointer Next points to the first son of that node and pointer bros that points to the next brother of the node.

I'm having a problem with my code that for some unknown reason creates an infinite number of brothers for a node and i have no idea why,
Was hoping you can take a look and maybe suggest where i went wrong.
Thank you!

Node Class:

```
class Node { 
private:
    int capacity;
    int price;
    int height;
    int num_of_leafs; // represents the total number of leafs under this branch
    Node* bros;     

public:
    Node* next;

    Node(){
        capacity = 0;          
        price = 0;
        height = 0;
        next = NULL;
        bros = NULL;
    }
    Node(int capacity_){
        capacity = capacity_;  
        price = 0;
        height = 0;
        next = NULL;
        bros = NULL;
    }                

    //should return true if this node has no children, false otherwise.
    bool isLeaf()
    { 
        if (this->next == NULL) { return 1; }
        else { return 0; }
    }

    // This methoed counts the number of leafs sons of this node.
    int Count_Leafs()
    {
        int num = 0;
        if (this->isLeaf()) { return num; }
        else {
            Node* iter = this->next;
            while ( iter != NULL )
            {
                if ( iter->isLeaf() ) { num++ ; } 
                iter = iter->bros;
            }
        }
        return num;
    }

    //this method adds a child to this node.
    void addChild(Node* child)
    {
        if ( child->height != 0 )
        {
            cout << "Node already in tree" ;
            return; }
        if( this->next == NULL ) 
        { 
            this->next = child;
        }
        else {
            Node* iter = this->next;
            while ( iter->getNextBro() != NULL ) { iter = iter->getNextBro(); }
            iter->setNextBro(child);
        }
        child->height = this->height + 1;
    }
        // this methoed checks if current node has brothers
    bool hasBro()
    {
        if ( this->getNextBro() == NULL ) { return 0;}
        else { return 1;}
    }
        Node* getNextBro()
    {
        return bros;
    }

    void setNextBro(Node* next)
    {
        this->bros = next;
    }

    int getHeight()
    {
        return this->height;
    }

    int getNumBros()
    {
        Node* iter = this->bros;
        int num=0;
        while ( iter != NULL )
        {
            num++;
            iter = this->getNextBro();
        }
        return num;
    }
```

And the tree creation:

```
    Node* s8 = new Node(8);
Node* s5 = new Node(5);
Node* s6 = new Node(6);
for(int i=0; i < 2 ; i++){
    s6->addChild(new Node());      
}

Node* s7 = new Node(7);
Node* s2 = new Node(2);
for(int i=0; i < 3 ; i++){
    s2->addChild(new Node());
}

Node* s3 = new Node(3);
Node* s2_2 = new Node(2);  
s2_2->addChild(new Node());

Node* s4 = new Node(4);
 for(int i=0; i < 5 ; i++){
    s4->addChild(new Node());
}

Node* s1 = new Node(1);
 for(int i=0; i < 2 ; i++){
    s1->addChild(new Node());      
}
Node* s2_3 = new Node(2);
 for(int i=0; i < 4 ; i++){
    s2_3->addChild(new Node());
}
Node* s2_4 = new Node(2);  
for(int i=0; i < 3 ; i++){
    s2_4->addChild(new Node());
}
s8->addChild(s5);
cout << "S5 bros: " << s5->getNumBros() << "\n";
cout << "S6 bros: " << s6->getNumBros() << "\n";
s8->addChild(s6);    
cout << "S5 bros: " << s5->getNumBros() << "\n";
s5->addChild(s7);
cout << "S5 bros: " << s5->getNumBros() << "\n";
s5->addChild(s2);
s6->addChild(s3);
s6->addChild(s2_2);
s7->addChild(s4);
s7->addChild(s1);
s3->addChild(s2_3);
s3->addChild(s2_4);
```

Thank you!

Comment: If we're to look for bugs in adding nodes, it would help to see all the node-adding code :-P You left out implementation of `getNextBro()` and `setNextBro()`. Also, which of the `addChild()` calls creates the infinite number of nodes?

Comment: Hi Angew , i added the functions though they are pretty straightforward.
The line S8->addChild(S6) creates the infinite number of brothers

Comment: I can't see anything obvious. Have you tried stepping through the code with a debugger?

Comment: Yeah , first time i ran it it just got stuck. so i added the getNumBros() function to see if the tree builds correctly. after a few tries i figured out that when i count the number of brothers for node S5 after s8->addChild(s6) the getNumBros() just goes on forever and i can't understand why because s6 bro variable is supposed to be NULL.

Comment: Code is useful for beginners to get a start on data structures and algorithm. I really used it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getNumBros()` is iterating over `this` rather than `iter`

```
iter = this->getNextBro();
```

Should be:

```
iter = iter->getNextBro();
```

Comment: funny how the function i created to help me find the bug in my program caused so much trouble - thanks JasonD.

Now i need to understand why my recursion function goes into an endless loop.